# Checking the type of relationship between columns in python/pandas? (one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, many-to-many, relational-database

Let's say I have 5 columns.

```
pd.DataFrame({
'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
'Column2': [4, 3, 6, 8, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3],
'Column3': [7, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7],
'Column4': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
'Column5': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
```

Is there a function to know the type of relationship each par of columns has? (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many)

An output like:

```
Column1 Column2 one-to-many
Column1 Column3 one-to-many
Column1 Column4 one-to-one
Column1 Column5 one-to-many
Column2 Column3 many-to-many
...
Column4 Column5 one-to-many
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
'Column2': [4, 3, 6, 8, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3],
'Column3': [7, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7],
'Column4': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
'Column5': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

def get_relation(df, col1, col2):        
    first_max = df[[col1, col2]].groupby(col1).count().max()[0]
    second_max = df[[col1, col2]].groupby(col2).count().max()[0]
    if first_max==1:
        if second_max==1:
            return 'one-to-one'
        else:
            return 'one-to-many'
    else:
        if second_max==1:
            return 'many-to-one'
        else:
            return 'many-to-many'

from itertools import product
for col_i, col_j in product(df.columns, df.columns):
    if col_i == col_j:
        continue
    print(col_i, col_j, get_relation(df, col_i, col_j))
```

output:

```
Column1 Column2 one-to-many
Column1 Column3 one-to-many
Column1 Column4 one-to-one
Column1 Column5 one-to-many
Column2 Column1 many-to-one
Column2 Column3 many-to-many
Column2 Column4 many-to-one
Column2 Column5 many-to-many
Column3 Column1 many-to-one
Column3 Column2 many-to-many
Column3 Column4 many-to-one
Column3 Column5 many-to-many
Column4 Column1 one-to-one
Column4 Column2 one-to-many
Column4 Column3 one-to-many
Column4 Column5 one-to-many
Column5 Column1 many-to-one
Column5 Column2 many-to-many
Column5 Column3 many-to-many
Column5 Column4 many-to-one
```

Comment: This output is not correct if I dont mistake. Column1 -> Column2 is one-to-many?

Comment: Well, I might agree with you, but this way it follows the convention of the question. You can switch many-to-one and one-to-many if you prefer the other way

Comment: Yes I agree, but for the sake of correctness, I would change it to the correct output, maybe OP was making a mistake. Btw upvoted, good answer +1

Comment: You are right, I swapped them. I also asked to edit the original post, to fix the question as well.  Thanks

Comment: Hey guys. The convention is one-to-many however for the question I'm interested in the order of the entities. That means the relationship of C1 to C2 is many-to-one and the relationship of C2 to C1 is one-to-many. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601703/difference-between-one-to-many-and-many-to-one-relationship/4601723

Comment: So employees(C1) 1,6, and 8 work for department(C2) 4. Many employees work for one department. many-to-one. Its a bit confusing because column one is unique. I didn't meant it to be a confusing example my bad

Comment: @italo you're confusing the set relationship with entity diagram relationship. Which is reverse. For example "many Employees work for one department" => Emp (N...1) Dept relation, which inturn has one-to-many set relation.

Answer (score 5):

This may not be a perfect answer, but it should work with some further modification:

```
a = df.nunique()
is9, is1 = a==9, a==1
one_one = is9[:, None] & is9
one_many = is1[:, None]
many_one = is1[None, :]
many_many = (~is9[:,None]) & (~is9)

pd.DataFrame(np.select([one_one, one_many, many_one],
                       ['one-to-one', 'one-to-many', 'many-to-one'],
                       'many-to-many'),
             df.columns, df.columns)
```

Output:

```
              Column1       Column2       Column3       Column4      Column5
Column1    one-to-one  many-to-many  many-to-many    one-to-one  many-to-one
Column2  many-to-many  many-to-many  many-to-many  many-to-many  many-to-one
Column3  many-to-many  many-to-many  many-to-many  many-to-many  many-to-one
Column4    one-to-one  many-to-many  many-to-many    one-to-one  many-to-one
Column5   one-to-many   one-to-many   one-to-many   one-to-many  one-to-many
```

Answer (score 3):

First we get all the combinations of the columns with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

Finally we use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `validate` argument to check for which relationship "passes" the test with `try, except`:

Notice, we leave out `many_to_many` since this relationship is not "checked", quoted from docs:

> “many_to_many” or “m:m”: allowed, but does not result in checks.

```
from itertools import product

def check_cardinality(df):

    combinations_lst = list(product(df.columns, df.columns))
    relations = ['one_to_one', 'one_to_many', 'many_to_one']

    output = []
    for col1, col2 in combinations_lst:
        for relation in relations:
            try:
                pd.merge(df[[col1]], df[[col2]], left_on=col1, right_on=col2, validate=relation)
                output.append([col1, col2, relation])
            except:
                continue

    return output

cardinality = (pd.DataFrame(check_cardinality(df), columns=['first_column', 'second_column', 'cardinality'])
               .drop_duplicates(['first_column', 'second_column'])
               .reset_index(drop=True))
```

**Output**

```
   first_column second_column  cardinality
0       Column1       Column1   one_to_one
1       Column1       Column2  one_to_many
2       Column1       Column3  one_to_many
3       Column1       Column4   one_to_one
4       Column1       Column5  one_to_many
5       Column2       Column1  many_to_one
6       Column2       Column4  many_to_one
7       Column3       Column1  many_to_one
8       Column3       Column4  many_to_one
9       Column4       Column1   one_to_one
10      Column4       Column2  one_to_many
11      Column4       Column3  one_to_many
12      Column4       Column4   one_to_one
13      Column4       Column5  one_to_many
14      Column5       Column1  many_to_one
15      Column5       Column4  many_to_one
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use Andrea's answer investigate some huge CSV files and was getting many-to-many for just about everything - even columns I was sure were 1-1. The problem was duplicates.

Here's a slightly modified version with a demo, and with a format that matches database terminology (and a description to remove ambiguity)

#### Firstly a clearer example

Doctors make many prescriptions which can each have several drugs prescribed, but each drug is made by one producer and each producer only makes one drug.

```
       doctor  prescription         drug producer
0  Doctor Who             1      aspirin    Bayer
1    Dr Welby             2      aspirin    Bayer
2       Dr Oz             3      aspirin    Bayer
3  Doctor Who             4  paracetamol  Tylenol
4    Dr Welby             5  paracetamol  Tylenol
5       Dr Oz             6  antibiotics    Merck
6  Doctor Who             7      aspirin    Bayer
```

#### Correct results from my functions below

Main changes to Andrea's:

- drop_duplicates on the pairs so that 1-1 does not get seen as many-many
- I put the results in a dataframe (see `report_df` in the function) to make it easier to read the results
- I reversed the logic to match UML terms (I'm staying out of the debate of set vs UML - this is just the way I wanted it)

```
        column 1      column 2   cardinality                                        description
0         doctor  prescription     1-to-many   each doctor has many prescriptions (some  had 3)
1         doctor          drug  many-to-many  doctors had up to 2 drugs, and drugs up to 3 d...
2         doctor      producer  many-to-many  doctors had up to 2 producers, and producers u...
3   prescription        doctor     many-to-1             many prescriptions (max 3) to 1 doctor
4   prescription          drug     many-to-1               many prescriptions (max 4) to 1 drug
5   prescription      producer     many-to-1           many prescriptions (max 4) to 1 producer
6           drug        doctor  many-to-many  drugs had up to 3 doctors, and doctors up to 2...
7           drug  prescription     1-to-many     each drug has many prescriptions (some  had 4)
8           drug      producer        1-to-1               1 drug has 1 producer and vice versa
9       producer        doctor  many-to-many  producers had up to 3 doctors, and doctors up ...
10      producer  prescription     1-to-many  each producer has many prescriptions (some  ha...
11      producer          drug        1-to-1               1 producer has 1 drug and vice versa
```

#### WRONG results without drop-duplicate below

These are based on my modified copy of Andrea's aglo without the drop-duplicates.

You can see how the last row - doctor-to-drug - is many-to-many when it should be 1-1 - that explains my initial results (which are hard to debug with 1000s of records)

```
           column 1      column 2   cardinality                                        description
0         doctor  prescription     1-to-many   each doctor has many prescriptions (some  had 3)
1         doctor          drug  many-to-many  doctors had up to 3 drugs, and drugs up to 4 d...
2         doctor      producer  many-to-many  doctors had up to 3 producers, and producers u...
3   prescription        doctor     many-to-1             many prescriptions (max 3) to 1 doctor
4   prescription          drug     many-to-1               many prescriptions (max 4) to 1 drug
5   prescription      producer     many-to-1           many prescriptions (max 4) to 1 producer
6           drug        doctor  many-to-many  drugs had up to 4 doctors, and doctors up to 3...
7           drug  prescription     1-to-many     each drug has many prescriptions (some  had 4)
8           drug      producer  many-to-many  drugs had up to 4 producers, and producers up ...
9       producer        doctor  many-to-many  producers had up to 4 doctors, and doctors up ...
10      producer  prescription     1-to-many  each producer has many prescriptions (some  ha...
11      producer          drug  many-to-many  producers had up to 4 drugs, and drugs up to 4...
```

#### New functions

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

def get_relation(df, col1, col2):
    # pair columns, drop duplicates (for proper 1-1), group by each column with 
    # the count of entries from the other column associated with each group 
    first_max = df[[col1, col2]].drop_duplicates().groupby(col1).count().max()[0]
    second_max = df[[col1, col2]].drop_duplicates().groupby(col2).count().max()[0]
    if first_max==1:
        if second_max==1:
            return '1-to-1', f'1 {col1} has 1 {col2} and vice versa'
        else:
            return 'many-to-1',f'many {col1}s (max {second_max}) to 1 {col2}'
    else:
        if second_max==1:
            return '1-to-many', f'each {col1} has many {col2}s (some  had {first_max})'
        else:
            return f'many-to-many', f'{col1}s had up to {first_max} {col2}s, and {col2}s up to {second_max} {col1}s'

def report_relations(df):
    report = [] 
    for col_i, col_j in product(df.columns, df.columns):
        if col_i == col_j:
            continue
        relation = get_relation(df, col_i, col_j)
        report.append([col_i, col_j, *relation])
    report_df = pd.DataFrame(report, columns=["column 1", "column 2", "cardinality", "description"])
    # formating
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000, 'display.width', 1000, 'display.max_rows',1000)
    # comment one of these two out depending on where you're using it
    display(report_df) # for jupyter
    print(report_df)   # SO

test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'doctor': ['Doctor Who', 'Dr Welby', 'Dr Oz','Doctor Who', 'Dr Welby', 'Dr Oz', 'Doctor Who'],
    'prescription': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'drug': [ 'aspirin', 'aspirin', 'aspirin', 'paracetemol', 'paracetemol', 'antibiotics', 'aspirin'],
    'producer': [ 'Bayer', 'Bayer', 'Bayer', 'Tylenol', 'Tylenol', 'Merck', 'Bayer']

})

display(test_df)
print(test_df)
report_relations(test_df)
```

Thank's Andrea - this helped me a lot.